# Powershell hang when execute commands

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am testing to create SCCM 2012 application deployment types via powershell and below is my command that is working. Im succesfully able to create the deployment types using below line of code

```
Add-CMDeploymentType -ApplicationName "PowerTest" -InstallationFileLocation "\\sccmserver\folder$\Powershell_Test\Sources\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi" -MsiInstaller -AutoIdentifyFromInstallationFile -ForceForUnknownPublisher $true -InstallationBehaviorType InstallForSystem -Language "English" -DeploymentTypeName 'Setup' -InstallationProgram "'code1.wsf' /SMSLaunch /foldername:Chrome 2.0.4'"
```

But the problem is when I add below parameters (**-MaximumAllowedRunTimeMinutes 20 -EstimatedInstallationTimeMinutes 10 -LogonRequirementType WhetherOrNotUserLoggedOn**). When I click enter, it seems unable to execute. It does not display any error but it just do not execute. I check in help, and below parameters do exist. Or is it because these parameters depends on other set of parameters that you have to specify first in order for it to able to run?

```
  -MaximumAllowedRunTimeMinutes 20 -EstimatedInstallationTimeMinutes 10 -LogonRequirementType WhetherOrNotUserLoggedOn
```

Comment: Hm, you could try to append `-Verbose` or `-Debug` to maybe get some hints

Comment: Below is the error im receiving if I add the -MaximumAllowedRunTimeMinutes parameters. Typing verbose also will display the same error as below


**Add-CMDeploymentType : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1**

Comment: So you should take a look at the Documentation and check the parameterset you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Parameters **-MaximumAllowedRunTimeMinutes** is actually part of **Set-CMDeploymentType** cmdlet and not **Add-CMDeploymentType**.